# How do you declare 'assigns' clause with multidimensional arrays in frama-c?

Tags: pointers, frama-c, arrays

I have the following variables:

```
int** send_count;
message_struct*** send_queue;
```

And I have a function I want to declare a contract for

```
message_record_struct postSend(int destination, double* buf);
```

How do I declare a contract which allows assignment to the elements of `send_count` and `send_queue`?

I'm concerned the following approach only allows assignment to the element at the address of pointer to the array:

```
@ assigns send_count
```

And the following approach throws an error given the `axiomatic theory { logic integer NP; }` in an earlier portion of the code):

```
@ assigns *(send_count+(0..NP-1));
@ assigns \forall integer i; 0<=i<NP ==>                                                                                                                                                                
          *(send_count[i]+(0..NP-1));
```

`$ frama-c -wp -wp-prover "why3ide" assign_example.c`

```
[kernel] Parsing FRAMAC_SHARE/libc/__fc_builtin_for_normalization.i (no preprocessing)

[kernel] Parsing assign_example.c (with preprocessing)

assign_example.c:62:[kernel] user error: syntax error (expression expected but predicate found) in annotation.

[kernel] user error: stopping on file "assign_example.c" that has errors. Add '-kernel-msg-key pp' for preprocessing command.

[kernel] Frama-C aborted: invalid user input.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you are looking for is probably

```
/*@ assigns *(send_count+(0..NP-1));
    assigns *(send_count[0..NP-1]+(0..NP-1));
```

ACSL ranges `[a..b]` have been introduced to keep assigns clauses quantifiers-free, and should be used as much as possible.

Comment: I guess that for the latter, `assigns \at(send_count[0 .. NP-1][0 .. NP-1], Post)` might be more appropriate. `assigns` clause are evaluated in the Pre state. Thus `assigns p, *p` means that you're modifying `p` and the location where `p` pointed to initially.